# script to move all files from one location to another location

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos

can someone help me with a dos script to move all files from one location to another location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
move <sourcepath>\*.* <destpath>
```

IE, if you wanted to move all files from c:\test\ to c:\test2

```
move c:\test\*.* c:\test2
```

if you want to suppress the prompt to overwrite files

```
move /Y c:\test\*.* c:\test2
```

If you want to move from the current directory, you can specify just the `*.*`.  Also you can do relative paths.  So if you want to move the current directory's files up one directory, you'd do

```
move *.* ..
```

`..` being the shortcut for "up one directory"

If it's across the network, you can use a UNC path to authenticate as the user you're logged in as or map a drive (using the `NET USE` command) to specify a username/password on the remote computer, then copy using that drive letter.  You can then delete the drive letter after you're done.  UNC paths look like `\\computer\share\folder\file.txt`

Comment: I think you mean across the network, not across the directory.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one

```
C:\> MOVE /Y *.* C:\Destination
```

should be corrected.

Comment: i accidentally marked it down, please edit it, and iw ill mark it back up

Answer (score 1):

Use Robocopy. In Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 you can even run it multi-threaded using the `/MT[:n]` switch. From my daily "sync-before-shutdown" script:

```
Robocopy "d:\dev" "\\dolores\backups\carrie\dev" /e /MT /njh /njs /nc /np /nfl /ndl
```

(all the `/n..` switches suppress console output which helps to speed up the copying process).

To move the files, use either `/MOV` or `/MOVE` (to move all subfolders) instead of `/E`.