# How to move output file in dos

Tags: dos, batch-file

I would like to create a batch file which will move the output file of a custom command "mdmg C:\source i5". I must execute this command from the C:\home directory where the mdmg.cmd resides.

This command converts the any file in the source dir and creates an output files in the C:\home folder.

However I want to move the output files to another folder autometically, lets say C:\test.

can it be done in a batch script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything you can do from the commandline can be done in a batch script; look up the `move` command. Personally, I think this type of question belongs more on superuser.

Comment: Looks like there are equally many DOS batch questions on Stackoverflow as on SuperUser. However, I happened to notice that this looks like it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259074/script-to-move-all-files-from-one-location-to-another-location

Comment: There are, but this is mostly a DOS command question, not a shell scripting question. Its use in a shell script is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

bla.bat

```
move c:\home\* c:\test
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem ? DOS has a [move](http://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) command. Or you could simulate that with a copy and delete if move is unavailable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself the trouble of the batch using CMD redirects. Just paste the following behind the mdmg.cmd command.

```
    > "C:\source i5\output.txt"
```

Basically the CMD interpreter will execute the command(s) in mdmg.cmd, and then redirect the output of the commands to print in `output.txt`. This way you don't have to call another batch. Another cool thing about doing it this way is that if the output file does not exist at the specified path, cmd.exe will make it for you.